# How do I delete the materials under this drop-down menu?

Tags: materials

I was making a couple Materials for a Mesh, and now every new material says "Material.001", "Material.002", and so on. I think it's because of these Materials under the Material icon next to the "+ New" button. How do I delete them?

[image]

No Materials appear under the Mesh's Data in the Outliner, so I can't delete them from there. I can select the Materials to create a  new, editable Material, but deleting that Material won't delete the ones under the icon.

Comment: The dropdown menu gives a list of available materials in the scene, they are not applied to the object - they are applied to no object as you can see from the "0" in front of almost all of them - that's why they don't show up under the object in the _Outliner_. The name suffixes "Material.001", "Material.002" etc. indicate that you created them by duplicating a material named "Material". The numbers will be added because they have no unique name. To get rid of them, delete them from the menu under _File_ > _Clean Up_ > _Unused Data-Blocks_.

Comment: Select one with a '0' against it and click the '-' button? You'll have to do this in Object mode. Alternatively you can save your Blend file and exit Blender. That will delete all the materials which aren't allocated to objects.

Comment: @JohnEason "Select one with a '0' against it and click the '-' button"? Closing the blend file and reopening makes much more sense ;) Selecting it would just put it on the object and the '-' button removes it again... so you're back where you were before when it had the '0'. And if you have very many of those '0' objects that's a lot of totally unnecessary work...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes. I agree. Anyway I guess he has enough suggestions to choose from now! :^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your materials have the "0" prefix they will be deleted as soon as you'll close your file. That said, you can remove them right away:

Go into *File > Clean Up > Unused Data-Blocks*:

[image]

Also if you switch the *Outliner* to *Orphan Data* you can see what are the unused datas, and click on the *Purge* button:

[image]